# Under what conditions could you (theoretically) reach the centre of a 2-sphere by traveling away from it?

Tags: low-dimensional-topology, noneuclidean-geometry

Comments have helped me hopefully sumarize the question better:  Is there a type of geometry under which center connects to periphery?

Edit:  Based on mr_e_man's comment below, I now believe what I'm looking for may be a sort of higher-dimensional analogue for a mobius strip.  Does such a thing exist?

---

Original Question:

I am not trained in mathematics so my language is imprecise.  My apologies.  Please keep your answers as free of high-level terminology as possible.

Under what conditions could you (theoretically) reach the centre of a 2-sphere by traveling away from it?  In other words, imagine you are a magical housefly not bound to three-dimensional space or by the rules which apply to most people's ordinary everyday conceptions of geometry. You are sitting on the exterior surface of a 2-sphere.  After a while, you lift off and fly as far as you can away from it some artibrary direction, only to find yourself at some distant point *within* the 2-sphere, at its center.

Intutively I feel this would be possible in four dimensions.  Am I right?  Or am I talking about some kind of non-euclidean geometry--or both--or neither?

Comment: I can't imagine this being possible with any reasonable definition of "moving away", at least definitely not in the Euclidean space of any dimension.

Comment: Without specifying what "moving away" means, your question is un-answerable.

Comment: @Moshekohan apologies for my lack of clarity.  I have edited my question to give an example of exactly what this looks like.

Comment: It's kind of a fun question, but the trouble is that it is quite a bad fit for our site. math.stackexchange is designed for precise and answerable mathematical questions. Four dimensional geometry and non-Euclidean geometry are both precise and well known mathematical concepts; *if* you knew what those were, *perhaps* there would be a precise question in one of those settings.

Comment: If this is part of the plot of a story you are writing, consider asking at the worldbuilding stackexchange. There you can explain how the need for this fits your plot.

Comment: @EthanBolker it isn't.  I'm genuinely interested.  Thank you though.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you.  It's seems like a suffiently precise and answerable question to me if an answer exists--which I assumed it did.  But by the responses here, it appears that perhaps it does not!  In which case you are right to say it's not a good question.  I'm going to attempt one last edit.

Comment: It's a fine question, but it depends on what you mean by sphere. Lowering the dimension for a minute, how would you make sense of the case of an (open) disk? It depends on what you mean by "moving away". Interpreting your question as following geodesic curvature, you could ask it there's a metric on the disk such that geodesics through the origin are closed paths. This is a perfectly reasonable question, but it's only one interpretation of your question and the answer will depend on the interpretation.

Comment: On a Mobius band, you can reach the "inside" of a circle from the "outside". (And by "circle" I mean something with length, not area.) Is this the kind of thing you're asking about, one dimension higher?

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes!  Thank you.  I didn't see the connection but this is what I mean.  Is there a higher-dimensional analogue?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen  Ahh, thank you.  In other words, say a 2D circle... if we 'move away' into three dimensions, there is indeed a path from the circle's exterior to the interior, but not if we move away within the circle's two dimensions.  I think this is why I intuitively thought my 'housefly' example might be possible in four dimensions.  It sounds as if what I'm talking about may be simply a characteristic of interacting with a closed n-dimensional shape in n+1 dimensions.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Although I have not accounted for the fact that we also have to move back towards the circle in three dimensions to get to its interior.  The pattern I'm talking about is more like mr_e_man's comment about the mobius strip... where somehow if you travel in exterior space long enough you're just naturally deposited in interior space.

Comment: I just remembered Mathologer's video [Hypertwist: 2-sided Möbius strips and mirror universes](https://youtu.be/6-4SCQpingg).

Comment: Actually, a torus is a simpler example than a Mobius band. You can travel from one side of a circle to the other side, without touching the circle or leaving the surface of the torus. The higher-dimensional version of this would be $\mathbb S^{n-1}\times\mathbb S^1$, the Cartesian product of a sphere and a circle.

Comment: @mr_e_man thanks--that was interesting!  Though his briefly-mentioned 3D mobius strip just looked like a mobius strip with walls and a ceiling which I guess makes sense lol.

Comment: @mr_e_man ahh, yeah!  Thanks!  That makes sense.  If there were a 'magic housefly' on the torus, like in my example, he would simply have to crawl along the 2-dimensional surface running from the outside curve of the torus to the 'donut hole' to move from outside the circle to inside it.  So presumably then, the four dimensional version would allow the 'magic housefly' to travel in three dimensions along a higher-dimensional toroidal curve between the exterior and interior of a sphere?